# Is it possible to make a function template take a `decltype` from a function reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've always had difficulty understanding the `std::function` template. It seems to use magic that I don't know yet.  It's template arguments are `class R`, `class... ARGS`.  Yet it can be passed to the template as `std::function<void>` or `std::function<void()>`.  An example with parameters: `std::function<void, int, float>` or `std::function<void(int, float)>`.  Was this 2nd syntax introduced in ***c++11***?  I don't think this was valid prior.

Also, is there a way to get the `decltype` of a function and pass it to the function template?  It would make setup of the function template so much easier.

Here is an example:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// this works
void x() {}
void y(int p0) {}

int main1()
{
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  function<decltype(y)> functors[] = { bind(x), bind(y, _1) };
  functors[0](1);
  functors[1](1);
  return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// this doesn't work
struct X
{
    void x() {}
    void y(int p0) {}
    void z(int i, int p0)
    {
      using namespace std::placeholders;
      static function<decltype(&X::y)> functors[] = { bind(&X::x, _1), bind(&X::y, _1, _2) };
      functors[i](this, p0);
    }
};

int main2()
{
  X xobj;
  xobj.z(0, 1);
  xobj.z(1, 1);
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return main1() + main2();
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempts with `decltype`. It should be possible to do what you want, but we ought to know what exactly you want.

Comment: OK I don't see why `decltype` would be illegal in this context. Seems a pretty standard and straightforward usage. Both gcc and clang compile it.

Comment: `decltype(y)` yields the type `void(int)`. IIRC, `bind` can take additional arguments which are ignored and not passed to the bound function, that's why `function<void(int)> f = bind(x)` works.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, the problem appears when I do this with member functions.

Comment: @Adrian There's no type *member function*, only a *pointer to member function*. It wouldn't make sense either, as `std::function` itself is an object, and member functions are called on objects. However, you can use some metaprogramming to create `function<void(int)>` via `function< as_free_function<&X::y>::type >`. `bind` expressions automatically create function objects from member function pointers by using the first argument as the object to call the member function on.

Comment: @DyP Yes I understand that bind uses the 1st arg as an object to call upon, but how do I create a free function pointer from the member function pointer?  There is no `as_free_function` template.

Comment: @Adrian: You can't create a free function from a pointer-to-member.  Do you mean you want to synthesize a free function pointer **type** with the same arguments and return type as a member function pointer **type**?

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes, that is exactly it.

Comment: `template< typename Target, typename R, typename... Args > class remove_memberness_from_pointer<R (Target::*)(Args...)> { typedef R (*type)(Args...); };`

Comment: @BenVoigt But this is not part of the STL?  And that's because?

Comment: @Adrian: You mean not part of the `type_traits` header in the Standard Library (STL is old, very very old, before there even was a C++ Standard).  Dunno, guess no one on the committee though of including it.  Or they couldn't find a good name.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think I would need: `template< typename Target, typename R, typename... Args > class remove_memberness_from_pointer<R (Target::*)(Args...)> { typedef R (*type)(Target*, Args...); };`, yes?

Comment: @Adrian: Well that's not removing memberness, that's converting the target to an explicit argument.  But yes, that's useful too.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, if I need to call that member function, I need the target to apply it to.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  So I would call that `unpack_memberness_from_function_pointer` or something like that -- it isn't removing the member information, but transforming it.

Comment: @BenVoigt, except it doesn't work. :(  Here's the [link](http://ideone.com/OJN2Ol) where the test is.

Comment: @Adrian I forgot the decltype, sorry: `however_you_want_to_call_it<decltype(&X::y)>::type`

Comment: @BenVoigt, now I get `error: storage size of ‘functors’ isn’t known`. :(  Why would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `decltype` thing you're looking for is probably something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct transform_to_free_function;

template <typename Target, typename R, typename... Args>
struct transform_to_free_function<R (Target::*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = R(Target*, Args...);
};
```

Note: 1) `type` is now a `public` member 2) it should rather be a function type, not a pointer for this purpose. It isn't straightforward to make a non-pointer type from a pointer type, but otherwise you had to use a `std::remove_pointer` on it.

The rest of your example then compiles fine:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct transform_to_free_function;

template <typename Target, typename R, typename... Args>
struct transform_to_free_function<R (Target::*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = R(Target*, Args...);
};

struct X
{
    void x() {}
    void y(int p0) {}
    void z(int i, int p0);
};

void X::z(int i, int p0)
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    static function<transform_to_free_function<decltype(&X::y)>::type>
    functors[] = { bind(&X::x, _1), bind(&X::y, _1, _2) };
    functors[i](this, p0);
}

int main()
{
    X xobj;
    xobj.z(0, 1);
    xobj.z(1, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice use of the newer syntax `using type = R(Target*, Args...);` instead of `typedef R (*type)(Target*, Args...);`.  However, why can't I get it to work using the old syntax?

Comment: @Adrian You can, you just shouldn't use a pointer type (because `std::function` expects a function type, not a pointer-to-function type). `typedef R type(Target*, Args...);` works fine.

Answer (score 4):

`std::function` accepts one template argument, which must be a function type. You cannot use `std::function<void, int, float>`. `std::function<void(int, float)>` is the only valid syntax.

`std::function` was introduced in C++11. There's no `std::function` prior to that. There was `std::tr1::function` though, defined in TR1, which used the same `std::function<void(int, float)>` syntax.

Comment: Oh, I must be misreading [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).  It states a template signature of `template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>`.  How do you read that?

Comment: @Adrian Yes, the second one is a specialization of the primary template (the first one).

Comment: Oh, right.  That makes sense.  So that syntax has been around from the beginning?  Why can't one populate the function template parameter with say `void(*)()`?  Looks like `void()` isn't actually a type.

Comment: @Adrian `void()` can be interpreted as the type *function with no parameters and no return value* and it can be interpreted as a no-op (specified as "create a prvalue of type `void`").

Comment: @DyP Oh yeah, that stupid vexing parse thing.  :r  But is a declaration a type?

Comment: @Adrian: you are misreading that page. It says `std::function` accepts one argument (the first declaration). It also says that the general template is undefined, so you cannot pass just any type to it. It also says there is a partial specialization defined, with several arguments, *but you cannot refer to it directly*. Quoth the standard: "Partial specialization declarations themselves are not found by name lookup. Rather, when the primary
template name is used, any previously-declared partial specializations of the primary template are also
considered."

Comment: @Adrian A declaration can introduce a type. `void()` can be interpreted as a type in the context `function<void()>` because `void()` is a valid *type-id* and because of [dcl.ambig.res]/2 (most vexing parse). A *type-id* "is syntactically a declaration for a variable or function of that type that omits the name of the entity" [dcl.name]/1

Comment: @Adrian: Obviously the implementation using variadic templates wasn't available prior to C++11... there were separate specializations for each number of parameters.  But the *usage* syntax hasn't changed.